# How to burn a cd at low speed?

Tags: installation, burning

I am trying to burn iso image of Lubuntu 11.10-alternate (I tried `active iso` and `free iso burner`). The problem is that the burning of cd should take place at low speed (i.e. 4x or low stated [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/CheckISO_CD) in second last topic) but as soon as I insert the cd (which is 52x speed) the option of 4x and lower disappears.

I have tried to find a less than 52x speed cd but haven't got one yet.

Now is there any trick or a software so that I could write an iso image at 4x or lower speed? I have tried writing iso images at higher speeds but the iso file gets corrupted (knew because checked the integrity of it right after the boot up) and I have gone through this process for four times.

Answer (score 1):

You will **only** be able to burn a cd at a speed as low as 4x **if** the media supports it; if not, programs will not be able to give you the option, but they will present to you the lowest speed that the disk is rated for (usually 10x or 16x today).

People have tried to force command-line programs such as `cdrecord` and `wodim` (a fork of `cdrecord`) to record at a lower speed, but have not succeeded as [these discussions](http://fedora.12.n6.nabble.com/Unable-to-force-wodim-to-write-a-CD-at-2X-speed-td4988076.html) and these at the [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1116091) show.

It is also unnecessary to burn an iso at such a low speed as 4x; the websites that tell you to do this contain outdated information. It is likely your problem lies in the software you are using rather than the speed of the burn. You mention `active iso` burner and `free iso burner` and yet those are both **Windows** programs; are you trying to do it in `Wine` or Windows? If you are actually using Ubuntu (and I'll continue my answer for the benefit of the Ubuntu users), I should use the command-line to burn the iso correctly. Install `wodim` with

```
sudo apt-get install wodim
```

Then place your media in the drive and find out about the speeds supported with

```
wodim -prcap dev=/dev/sr1
```

Which will give something like this:

```
Number of supported write speeds: 5
  Write speed # 0:  8467 kB/s CLV/PCAV (CD  48x, DVD  6x)
  Write speed # 1:  7056 kB/s CLV/PCAV (CD  40x, DVD  5x)
  Write speed # 2:  5645 kB/s CLV/PCAV (CD  32x, DVD  4x)
  Write speed # 3:  4234 kB/s CLV/PCAV (CD  24x, DVD  3x)
  Write speed # 4:  2822 kB/s CLV/PCAV (CD  16x, DVD  2x)
```

The lowest here is 16x, which is write speed 4, so with this knowledge you can enter the following and burn an iso (subsituting your drive device name):

```
wodim -eject -tao speed=4 dev=/dev/sr1 -v -data /my/iso/location.iso
```

Occasionally the speed setting is not honoured on some drives by `wodim`, so if not, just choose the lowest speed in a gui burner program such as `k3b` or `Xfburn`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Brasero. When the dialog box for burning images comes change then speed to the lowest as you wish. 4x speed is possible in Brasero!

Comment: As of today, the minimum speed offered by Brasero is 16x